# Animate element transform rotate

Tags: jquery, transform

How would I rotate an element with a jQuery's `.animate()`? I'm using the line below, which is currently animating the opacity correctly, but does this support CSS3 transforms?

```
$(element).animate({
   opacity: 0.25,
   MozTransform: 'rotate(-' + -amount + 'deg)',
   transform: 'rotate(' + -amount + 'deg)'
});
```

Comment: There is a jQuery plugin that will animate CSS transforms. Works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and Internet Explorer. https://github.com/puppybits/QTransform

Comment: Ended here in a search with the same topic, and downladed the plugin; works fine, but it caused a conflict with this instruction in another plugin I made:  $("#"+self.id).css("transform", "scale(1)"); I changed this line: elem.style[$.cssProps.transform] = val+'%'; to this: if ( isNaN(val) ) elem.style[$.cssProps.transform] = val;
                else elem.style[$.cssProps.transform] = val+'%'; Think it doesn´t need further explanation.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

As far as I know, basic animates can't animate non-numeric CSS properties.

I believe you could get this done using a [step](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function and the appropriate css3 transform for the users browser.  CSS3 transform is a bit tricky to cover all your browsers in (IE6 you need to use the Matrix filter, for instance).

**EDIT**: here's an example that works in webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari):  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ERRmd/

If you wanted to support IE9 only, you could use `transform` instead of `-webkit-transform`, or `-moz-transform` would support FireFox.

The trick used is to animate a CSS property we don't care about (`text-indent`) and then use its value in a step function to do the rotation:

```
$('#foo').animate(
..
step: function(now,fx) {
  $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
}
...
```

Comment: This is a painful solution both regarding code maintenance and speed. Forget `jQuery` while `transform`ing, check my solution.

Comment: What about if you have value that changes all the time to rotate, not fixed one ?

Answer (score 81):

[Ryley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5463375/282110) is great, but I have text within the element. In order to rotate the text along with everything else, I used the border-spacing property instead of text-indent.

Also, to clarify a bit, in the element's style, set your initial value:

```css
#foo {
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Then in the animate chunk, your final value:

```
$('#foo').animate({  borderSpacing: -90 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');  
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');
```

In my case, it rotates 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

[Here is the live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HwTMb/2/).

Comment: using z-index is also a good option if you're not using it anywhere else. but you wouldn't want to go negative on that one.

Comment: You might want to add the -ms- and -o- extensions as well (see http://css3please.com/)

Comment: How can you animate additional properties at the same time?

Comment: @MadTurki, I wrote an answer to your question below!

Comment: jQuery is actually smart enough to add all of the -moz-, -webkit-, etc prefixes for you, so you can simplify this code a bit. very good answer. +1

Comment: yes. very useful answer! can be improved a little but still very good

Comment: edited to remove the vendor specific transforms. modern jQuery FTW!

Comment: Does anyone know which dummy CSS property is acceptable for floating point values? I want to use this for the CSS scale() transform (normal values of 0 to 1) The borderSpacing property seems to round the values.

Answer (score 51):

In my opinion, jQuery's `animate` is a bit overused, compared to the CSS3 `transition`, which performs such animation on any 2D or 3D property. Also I'm afraid, that leaving it to the browser and [**by forgetting the layer called JavaScript could lead to spare CPU juice**](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/) - specially, when you wish to blast with the animations. Thus, I like to have animations where the style definitions are, since **you define functionality with JavaScript**. The more presentation you inject into JavaScript, the more problems you'll face later on.

All you have to do is to use `addClass` to the element you wish to animate, where you set a class that has CSS `transition` properties. You **just "activate" the animation**, which stays **implemented on the pure presentation layer**.

*.js*

```
// with jQuery
$("#element").addClass("Animate");

// without jQuery library
document.getElementById("element").className += "Animate";
```

One could easly [remove a class with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/), or [remove a class without library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript?lq=1).

*.css*

```
#element{
    color      : white;
}

#element.Animate{
    transition        : .4s linear;
    color             : red;
    /** 
     * Not that ugly as the JavaScript approach.
     * Easy to maintain, the most portable solution.
     */
    -webkit-transform : rotate(90deg);
}
```

*.html*

```
<span id="element">
    Text
</span>
```

This is a fast and convenient solution for most use cases.

I also use this when I want to implement a different styling (alternative CSS properties), and wish to change the style on-the-fly with a global .5s animation. I add a new class to the `BODY`, while having alternative CSS in a form like this:

*.js*

```
$("BODY").addClass("Alternative");
```

*.css*

```
BODY.Alternative #element{
    color      : blue;
    transition : .5s linear;
}
```

This way you can apply different styling with animations, without loading different CSS files. You only involve JavaScript to set a `class`.

Comment: That's fine, but it is limited to [browsers that support CSS3 transitions](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition).  So, no IE8 or IE9.  That's a pretty big segment to give up.

Comment: @Ryley You are talking about [12% percentage](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) of users. IE8 or IE9 users are below 5%. Its not a pretty big segment to give up, as we still talking about the presentation layer and not the functionality. About 5% of your visitors won't see your 3D animations. **Also if a browser (IE) does not support `transition`, it certainly won't support your transformations either.**

Comment: That's not entirely true - `transform` is supported by IE9.  But I agree that it's not the biggest user group to give up (IE8).

Comment: @Dyin It isn't a flat 12%, it depends on your target demographic. 50% of my firm's users are on IE8 according to google-analytics. The key is to know your audience.

That being said: bravo dude! This answer is much better than the top two. Way to be the "diamond in the rough".

Comment: Truly it depends, but we are talking in generality. When I'm developing a web-service for a "HTTP-compatible" smart-fridge, I can't expect my `transition` or `rotate3d` to get rendered. We should aim our solutions for common scenarios, if otherwise not requested.

Comment: I have to agree with Ziggy here. It depends on your audience, we are looking at about 80% of our users on IE8 and Windows XP. Pretty horrible, but that is what we have to deal with!

Comment: @tribe84 We should aim our solutions for common, general scenarios, if otherwise not requested.

Comment: This also does not account for dynamic rotation values.

Answer (score 19):

To add to the answers of Ryley and atonyc, you don't actually have to use a real CSS property, like `text-index` or `border-spacing`, but instead you can specify a fake CSS property, like `rotation` or `my-awesome-property`. It might be a good idea to use something that does not risk becoming an actual CSS property in the future.

Also, somebody asked how to animate other things at the same time. This can be done as usual, but remember that the `step` function is called for every animated property, so you'll have to check for your property, like so:

```
$('#foo').animate(
    {
        opacity: 0.5,
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        myRotationProperty: 45
    },
    {
        step: function(now, tween) {
            if (tween.prop === "myRotationProperty") {
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
                $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
                // add Opera, MS etc. variants
                $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');  
            }
        }
    });
```

(Note: I can't find the documentation for the "Tween" object in the jQuery documentation; from [the animate documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) there is a link to http://api.jquery.com/Types#Tween which is a section that doesn't appear to exist. You can find the code for the Tween prototype on Github [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js)).

Comment: what is myRotationProperty...is it something custom you defined; and what is `now` depends on this one.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - yes, `myRotationProperty` is something custom, a made-up, "fake" CSS property. `now` is the first argument to the step callback function, specifying the change to the property value at this step.

Comment: then did you also initialize this property in css too. Or you can just put it animate it takes it zero.

Answer (score 9):

Just use CSS transitions:

```
$(element).css( { transition: "transform 0.5s",
                  transform:  "rotate(" + amount + "deg)" } );

setTimeout( function() { $(element).css( { transition: "none" } ) }, 500 );
```

As example I set the duration of the animation to 0.5 seconds.

Note the `setTimeout` to remove the `transition` css property after the animation is over (500 ms)

---

For readability I omitted vendor prefixes.

This solution requires browser's transition support off course.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. You also forgot a semicolon behind your closing parenthese.

Comment: @Sorrow123444 I'm glad it worked for you. I fixed the missing semicolon, thank you

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this post, looking to use CSS transform in jQuery for an infinite loop animation. This one worked fine for me. I don't know how professional it is though.

```
function progressAnim(e) {
    var ang = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
        ang += 3;
        e.css({'transition': 'all 0.01s linear',
        'transform': 'rotate(' + ang + 'deg)'});
    }, 10);
}
```

Example of using:

```
var animated = $('#elem');
progressAnim(animated)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//this should allow you to replica an animation effect for any css property, even //properties //that transform animation jQuery plugins do not allow

            function twistMyElem(){
                var ball = $('#form');
                document.getElementById('form').style.zIndex = 1;
                ball.animate({ zIndex : 360},{
                    step: function(now,fx){
                        ball.css("transform","rotateY(" + now + "deg)");
                    },duration:3000
                }, 'linear');
            }
```