# jQuery script for random images to transition inside div at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a Javascript script that will take 10 images and have them fly into a div, one beside an other. The images should fly in at random, and there should be a different transition for each image.

The script is about 80% complete - I am successfully randomly flying 10 icons onto the div, but they all have the same transitions. How would I give them each their own transition, like rotate, ect?

Below is my jQuery code:

```
var av_icons = ["/2015/06/icon1.png",
    "/2015/06/icon2.png",
    "/2015/06/icon3.png",
    "/2015/06/icon4.png",
    "/2015/06/icon5.png",
    "/2015/06/icon6.png",
    "/2015/06/icon7.png",
    "/2015/06/icon8.png",
    "/2015/06/icon9.png",
    "/2015/06/icon10.png"
];

function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}
shuffle(av_icons);

$(".icon-slider").css("position", "relative");
var timeout = 0;
var left = 0;
var count = 0;
var top = 1000;
$.each(av_icons, function(index, value) {
            if (left > 600) {
                left = 0;
                top = 1090;
            }
            timeout += 500;
            left += 150;
            count++;
            $(".icon-slider").append("<img src='http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads" + value + "' height='80' width='90' class='av_icon_" + index + "' />");
            $(".av_icon_" + index).css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": "-1000px",
                "text-indent": "90px"
            }); //text-indent is supposed to help rotate the images as they fly on screen, but this does not work.
            $(".av_icon_" + index).animate({
                textIndent: 0,
                top: "+=" + top,
                left: "+=" + left,
                step: function(now, fx) {
                    $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'); //supposed to help rotate the images as they fly on screen, but this does not work.
                },
            }, timeout, function() {});
```

Comment: A jsFiddle with what you have working so far would be very helpful for us to make further tests.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the step function you could generate a random number, say between 1 and 5, and then do a switch on that number with a different transition in each case.

For example:

```
//Generate a random number between 1 and 5
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
switch(num) {
case(1):
    transition 1;
    break;
//and so on
}
```

Edit: Sorry I just understood your question a bit better. You can apply different types of animation by using the easing property of the jQuery animate function. You'll find more information on the available types here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

There is a similar question here ([Using Step function in animate to transform-rotate an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306971/using-step-function-in-animate-to-transform-rotate-an-element)) where this is suggested.

```
$(this).css ({"-moz-transform":"rotate("+now+"deg)",
                  "-webkit-transform":"rotate("+now+"deg)",
                  "-ms-transform":"rotate("+now+"deg)",
                  "-o-transform":"rotate("+now+"deg)"});
}, duration: 5000}, "linear");
```

Comment: No no, you answered my question flawlessly. I would actually like to somehow combine the different animations within the step function... how would I do that? This doesn't seem to work: step: function(now,fx) {
      var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      switch(num) {
     case(1):
       $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
       break;
       case(2):
       $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew('+now+'deg) translate(0px)');
       break;
      }

Comment: The step function that you've shown in your question looks like it should work to me, although it is specific to Google Chrome (and other webkit browsers). I'm not able to test any code right now but you could try this... I'll edit my previous answer.