# Chrome 21 scaling elements during rotation

Tags: google-chrome, css, rotation, css-animations

I think this is a bug in the latest Chrome (21.0.1180.57), but I thought I'd post here just to double check.

I'm changing the rotation of an element using javascript, and using webkit transitions to animate the rotation. Sometimes, depending on the start and end rotation, the element randomly scales along with the rotation. I've made a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/XCwUQ/ (click the body).

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Cheers,

Christian

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Chrome 21 on Linux.

Comment: Interesting, bug seems evident on Windows and OSX for me, but I don't have Linux to test.

Comment: have this problem as well, the animation would show it's first frame and stays like that, if it's a keyframe animation, it would show it's last frame when the animation finishes; check this : http://daneden.me/animate/ ; all the ROTATION effects is not working

Comment: confirmed Chrome 21.0.1180.57 on linux(fedora 17) does not have this issue; anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Working ok on Ubuntu 12.04 but on MacOS X 10.6.8 on Chrome 21.0.1180.57 I'm having the same issue.... any ideas?

Comment: I've submitted a [bug report to Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139994), hopefully they fix this soon. It's hard telling clients that it's not your fault and there's nothing you can do to fix it.

Comment: Excellent, I'm having a similar problem but with Firefox 14 on MacOs and Ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821553/css3-animation-under-firefox-14

Comment: still happens. sometimes at least (\w chrome 22.0.1229.94, MacOSX Lion)

Comment: add a note to the chromium issue, the more people the better :) http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139994

Comment: Who doesn't love browser bugs :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome 23.0.1271.64 on Windows 7. May be fixed now.

Comment: Fixed in Chrome 23.0.1271.64 on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: Seems to be fixed now in Chrome 23.** (See @joequincy comment on the original question)

---

Indeed, this seems like a bug. Until it is fixed, you can work around with the jQuery `animate()` function like this:

```
$(function() {
    var rotation = 163;
    $('body').on('click', function() {
        rotation = (rotation == 163) ? 198 : 163;               
        $('#wheel').animate({
            borderSpacing: rotation
        }, {
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');    
                $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');    
                $(this).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');    
                $(this).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');    
                $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');    
            }
        });        
    });
});​
```

Remove the `transition` CSS statements and add:

```
border-spacing: 163px;
```

This example misuses the `border-spacing` attribute, since it won't affect your layout in most cases.

See http://jsfiddle.net/hongaar/wLTLK/1/

(Thanks to this answer: [Animate element transform rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate))

*NOTE*: You can optionally use the jQuery transform plugin to remove the ugly multiple `css()` calls and for a simpler version of the `animate()` syntax (but adding overhead). See https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js

Comment: @Christian Varga - still not your fault, but now you can do something about it! :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, also can confirm the latest Chrome fixed it. So now we have 2 ways to address the issue :)