# CSS3 Animation under Firefox 14

Tags: html, firefox, css, css-animations

I'm having problems with the following animation:

```css
.anim {
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-duration: 6s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-name: animation_1;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    background-image:url("http://jsfiddle.net/css/../img/logo.png");    
    height:25px;
    width:  160px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;

}

.container {
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

@-moz-keyframes animation_1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        left:29.45px;
        top:0;
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2,2);
    }

    100% {
        top:0;
        opacity: 0.5;
        left:120px;
        top:120px;
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.5,0.5);
    }
}
```

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QTeXG/5/

Well, the same animation is working ok for Chrome 21: http://jsfiddle.net/P2dKE/

If I:
 - remove the opacity from the animation in Firefox it starts to work ok.
 - remove the background image and use a background color it also starts to work ok.

Tested under Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox 14.0.1 and Chrome 21.0.1180.57.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your jsFiddle works for me in Firefox 14.0.1 on Windows Vista.

Comment: Yup, if i use code with -webkit- and replace all -webkit- with -moz- works fine in Firefox, same effect like in Chrome. I'm on Windows, maybe is some bug with ff on Ubuntu

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a bug in Ubuntu and MacOS, in Windows is working ok, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I've tested this in Firefox 15 (beta) and I could not reproduce the problem.... It seems to be fixed in Firefox 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved in versions >= 15 of Firefox.