# Rotate a div on button press JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, jquery-animate

Trying to animate a `div` when the user clicks on a particular button on the UI. It's just meant to be a simple animation. Below is my code. Everything works fine except for this line

```
transform:"rotate(260deg)"
```

I am using Google Chrome and I know that it should be `-webkit` but this throws an error in the code.

```
    $("#anim2").on("click", function(){
            console.log("anim2");
            b1.animate({
                left:"250px",
                height:"20px",
                width:"20px",
                opacity:"0.5",
                transform:"rotate(260deg)"
    });
});
```

Any ideas how I can adjust it so it will work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate element transform rotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate)

Comment: jquery dosen't work that way use CSS3 transions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can plug into your javascript, but on :hover, this CSS process should do the trick for rotations in Chrome...

```
transform:rotate(deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(260deg);
```

But you could create a CSS class that sets these rules, and invoke that class .on('click'), within your jQuery.

Comment: You could also try using :active within your CSS to get the "click" feel of invoking that process.