# How to put a duration on a css3 rotation in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

This snippet works fine:

```
$("myelement").css({ rotateY(50deg) '})
```

I want this rotation to last 0.3second for instance

I tried with: but no success

```
$("myelement").css({transform: 'transition: all 0.3s ease-in; rotateY(50deg) '})
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate).

Comment: You should add your full code if you expect any answers.

Answer (score 2):

Separate the `transform` and `transition` properties.

```
$("myelement").css({
  transition: 'all 0.3s', 
  transform: 'rotateY(50deg)'
});
```

And here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/f7rwryeu/).