# How do I have an object rotate and then dissapear in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm working on making a mobile menu button and I want it to rotate 90 degrees and then disappear but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

I tried using .animate() for the rotation and then a callback that used hide() but that didn't work.

My latest code looks like:

```js
$('.menuButton').click(function() {
  $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
  setTimeout( function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', '0');
  }, 1000);
});//end click
```

```html
<div class="menuButton"></div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a possibility to use CSS animations then I highly recommend taking advantage of [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

It has a list of pre-made animations that are easy to apply, and you can use jQuery to simply add the class or remove it.

**Check out the simple demo below.**

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';
  
  $('#run-animation').on('click', runAnimation);
  
  function runAnimation(){
    var target = $('.my-animate-target');
    target.addClass('rotateOut');
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      target.removeClass('rotateOut');
    }, 2000);
  }
  
}());
```

```css
.container{
  margin:30px;
}
.my-animate-target{
  width:300px;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#run-animation{
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container"> 
<div class="my-animate-target animated">
  <h1>Watch Me Go!</h1>
</div>
<button type="button" id="run-animation">Run Animation</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that the jQuery methods are attractive, but one of the easiest ways to do this is to put your animation into a CSS class, and then use jQuery to add that class to your element.  All of the magic happens within `transition`.  In this case, we tell the element that any changes to transform will take 1 second.  Likewise, any changes to opacity will wait 1 second before beginning, and then will take half a second to execute.

```
.menuButton {
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 500ms 1s;
}
.menuButton.hideMe {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Now, your jquery call will be:

```
$('.menuButton').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hideMe');
});//end click
```

Try it yourself with the following example:  http://jsfiddle.net/dancingplatypus/qgnmk6s3/

Comment: Simple. Elegant. Easy. Thank you! I didn't even think of doing it like that.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way you can do this:

```
$("#image").click(function(){
$(this).rotate(90);
$(this).hide(1000);
});
```

Try to look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/RwEme/8572/

Answer (score 0):

Because transform doesn't have a strictly numeric value (needs, rotate, scale, etc)...it won't work with the Jquery animate (mostly only works with numeric values) without some work. Please see this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate) for some suggestions besides Josh's