# Why isn't this div rotating?

Tags: jquery, animation, rotation, transform

Anyone know why my `.rotate` div isn't rotating on page load?

```
<div class="rotate">ROTATE</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".rotate").animate({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(180deg)",
        "-moz-transform": "rotateY(180deg)",
        "-o-transform": "rotateY(180deg)",
        "-ms-transform": "rotateY(180deg)",
        "transform": "rotateY(180deg)",
      }, 2000);
    }, 900);
  });
</script>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rercw6f6/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate element transform rotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't properly support transform.

Luckily there is this jQuery addon to do it.
http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.transform.js/