# explaination of Animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Why does it animate the element from begin of left not from it's position to 100 pixel left

```
$("selector").animate({left: "+100px"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for jQuery's [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> "If a value is supplied with a leading `+=` or `-=` sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property."

So, use this syntax:

```js
$("div").animate({
  left: "+=100px"
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: thanks bro .but  can i scale it from its size to 10 while it animating

Comment: Which CSS property are you trying to animate? If you like, you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31887093/edit) to add a new example.

Comment: according to original questing (animating to left 100px from its position )

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. My demo animates 100px left from the original position. What do you mean by "scale it from its size to 10"?

Comment: i meaning decrease size of image form its original size to 10 .i  can do this by  scale transformation in css but i do not know to to do this the moving of image from it`s position to 100 pixel left.

Comment: So you are trying to animate both the `left` and a CSS `transform`? You can't *directly* animate a non-numeric property, but you might find a solution here: [Animate element transform rotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate)