# Can we use += to transform:rotate( 'x'deg); css property via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

This is my code :

```css
#move{
 height:70px;
 width:70px;
 border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="button" value="Move Right" onclick="
  $('#move').css({'background-color':'aqua'});
  $('#move').css({'position':'absolute',
                               'transition':'500ms ease-in-out',
                               'right':'-=50px',
                               'transform':'rotate(+=5deg)'});
  "></input>
        
        <br>
        OBJECT
        <br>
  <div id="move"></div>
```

And My Question goes like this :

Is it possible to make my div move AND rotate with +5 degree every time the button "MOVE RIGHT" is clicked by adding the operator such as `+=` to the `rotate` value in the CSS property, like this :

```
'transform':'rotate(+=5deg)'
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see if it works?  I don't think it will ...

Comment: Already been answered here -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate

Comment: what you can do is pure JS or pure CSS animation, otherwise you can create different CSS classes like `rotate5` `rotate10` `rotate15` ... and use Js to switch them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the `transform` property can have different values, which are **not commutative**. For example, the following values produce different results:

```css
transform: translateX(100px) rotate(90deg); /* This is different... */
transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100px); /* ... than this!       */
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#box1 {
  transform: translateX(100px) rotate(90deg);
}
#box2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
```

One may think that rotating `45deg` more would be

```css
transform: translateX(100px) rotate(135deg); /* OK    */
transform: rotate(135deg) translateX(100px); /* FAIL! */
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#box1 {
  transform: translateX(100px) rotate(135deg);
}
#box2 {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
```

However, that would only work for the first example, because `rotate` was the last transform function. In general, the proper way would be

```css
transform: translateX(100px) rotate(90deg) rotate(45deg); /* OK */
transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100px) rotate(45deg); /* OK */
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#box1 {
  transform: translateX(100px) rotate(90deg) rotate(45deg);
}
#box2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
```

Then, you can add this method:

```js
$.fn.addTransform = function(val) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var tr = $(this).css('transform');
    if(tr === 'none') tr = '';
    $(this).css('transform', tr + ' ' + val);
  });
};
```

And use it like

```js
$('#move').addTransform('rotate(5deg)');
```

```js
$.fn.addTransform = function(val) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var tr = $(this).css('transform');
    if(tr === 'none') tr = '';
    $(this).css('transform', tr + ' ' + val);
  });
};
$('input').click(function() {
  $('#move').css({
    backgroundColor: 'aqua',
    position: 'absolute',
    transition: '500ms ease-in-out',
    right: '-=50px'
  }).addTransform('rotate(5deg)');
});
```

```css
#move {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Move Right" />
<div id="move"></div>
```

Comment: Wow ! Thanks you so much ! I appreciate for your kind reply and help ! this was exactly what I was looking for.