# Transform isn't working with jQuery .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I noticed that whenever I try to use transform with a jQuery animation in the css section, it doesn't go off. It is the only property not working for me.

I am trying to use:

```
$(myElement).animate({
    opacity: 1, 
    transform: "scale(1.5)"
}, 7000);
```

But the above code only passes the opacity animation, ignoring the transform.

Comment: [From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/): "*All animated properties should be animated to a **single numeric value**, [...]*" – Related: [Animate element transform rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate)

Comment: So there is no way to .animate() transform, even though it is an animatable css property?

Comment: Not automatically, other than to just use CSS itself. –
 Note that jQuery's `.animate()` was created 6-7 years before CSS [Transforms](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms/) became standard (2006 vs. 2012-2013). It's a purely-JavaScript implementation and was only designed to support fully-numeric styles. – That said, you can use its `step:` options, as shown in the other Q&A I linked, to fill in support for other styles using expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the .animate() function, this would work.

```js
$(myElement).animate({
    height: ($(this).height()*1.5),
    width: ($(this).width()*1.5)
}, 7000);
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use css for the animation and jquery to add the class that does the animation.

```js
$(myElement).addClass("animate");
```

```css
.animate {
  transition: all 7s;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: It works, but I was trying to use .animate() in order to use velocity.js, since my website was lagging hard.

Comment: OK. I found a way to do it with .animate(). Will post another answer now