# Jquery animate doesn't work with transform property

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-animate

So when i try to use Jquery `animate` function it does't work at all. I tried every-single thing and still doesn't work. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

      $(".show").click(function () {
        $(".error-box").animate({
          transform: "translateX(0%)",
        }, 500);
      });
    </script>

    <style>
      .error-box {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="error-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore,
      excepturi?
    </div>
    <button class="show">Göster</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [animate-element-transform-rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using animation by adding a class with rule `transform: translateX(0%)`. Like that:

```
$(".error-box").addClass('animate');
```

Add animation delay `transition: .5s` to `.error-box` and add this class to your css:

```
.error-box.animate {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

As a result, you will get the desired result.

```js
$(".show").click(function () {
  $(".error-box").addClass('animate');
});
```

```css
.error-box {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: .5s;
}

.error-box.animate {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="error-box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, excepturi?
</div>
<button class="show">Göster</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CSS for animation? That is exactly what jQuery is doing :)

```js
$(".show").click(function () {
  $(".error-box").css({
    transform: "translateX(0%)",
  });
});
```

```css
.error-box{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:2px 4px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  position:relative;
  transform:translateX(-110%);
  transition:all 500ms;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="error-box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore,
  excepturi?
</div>
<br>
<button class="show">Göster</button>
```